# How should I compile this spark example?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark cluster and I am actually running the example given on the spark website.

```
/*** SimpleJob.scala ***/
import spark.SparkContext
import SparkContext._

object SimpleJob extends Application {
  val logFile = "//var//log//syslog" // Should be some file on your system
  val jarName:Seq[String] = "target//scala-2.9.2//simple-project_2.9.2-1.0.jar"
  val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Simple Job", "/home/subodh/Downloads/spark-0.6.1/bin",jarName)
  val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
  val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
  val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
  println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
}
```

When I compile this using sbt package command, it gives me following error :

```
[error] /home/subodh/Downloads/spark-0.6.1/example/src/main/scala/SimpleJob.scala:7: type mismatch;
**[error]  found   : java.lang.String("target//scala-2.9.2//simple-project_2.9.2-1.0.jar")
[error]  required: Seq[String]**
[error]   val jarName:Seq[String] = "target//scala-2.9.2//simple-project_2.9.2-1.0.jar"
[error]                             ^
[error] one error found
[error] {file:/home/subodh/Downloads/spark-0.6.1/example/}default-9e9e7d/compile:compile: Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jan 31, 2013 11:31:21 PM
```

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jarName` was declared as type `Seq[String]` but you gave it the `String` "target//scala-2.9.2//simple-project_2.9.2-1.0.jar". Changing the value to `Seq("target//scala-2.9.2//simple-project_2.9.2-1.0.jar")` fixes it.

```
scala> val jarName:Seq[String] = Seq("target//scala-2.9.2//simple-project_2.9.2-1.0.jar")
jarName: Seq[String] = List(target//scala-2.9.2//simple-project_2.9.2-1.0.jar)
```